# Question about polynomial ring and coefficients

Tags: polynomials

Let $R=k[x_0,...,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n+1$ variables and let $F=c_1f_1+ \cdots +c_kf_k \in R$ with $c_i \in k$. Is it possible to multiply $F$ with some element from $k$ such that the coefficients of all $f_i$ becomes the same? I.e does it exist an $a \in k$ such that $a \cdot F=cf_1+ \cdots +cf_k$?

Comment: Wouldn't $a=c=0$ work?

Answer (score 1):

As $a F = a c_1 f_1 + \dots + a c_k f_k$, the questions is really if given 
$c_1 , \dots, c_k$ there is an $a$ such that $ac_1 = \dots = ac_k$.

However, if $a\neq 0$, then $a c_i = a c_j $ if and only if $c_i = c_j$. 
While for $a=0$ of course $ac_i = ac_j$.

Thus, yes $a=0$ works, but this might not be what you want. 
Other than that, no, except the $c_i$ are all equal in the first place.